# Vue / Laravel - Axios post multiple field

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I created a component that can add additional fields by pressing a button. I don't know how would I submit this in the database with `axios.post` and laravel controller. I was able to achieve it in the past with the use of jquery and pure laravel, but I'm confused how to implement it in vue and axios.

**Component.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
        <td><strong>File</strong></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.id">
        <td><v-text-field outlined v-model="row.title" /></td>
        <td><v-text-field outlined v-model="row.description" /></td>
        <td>
          <label class="fileContainer">
          <input type="file" @change="setFilename($event, row)" :id="index">
          </label>
        </td>
        <td><a @click="removeElement(index);" style="cursor: pointer">X</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <div>
      <v-btn @click="addRow()">Add row</v-btn>
      <v-btn class="success" @click="save()">Save</v-btn>
      <pre>{{ rows | json}}</pre>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: ()=> ({
      rows: []
    }),
    methods: {
      addRow() {
        var elem = document.createElement('tr');
        this.rows.push({
          title: "",
          description: "",
          file: {
            name: 'Choose File'
          }
        });
      },
      removeElement(index) {
          this.rows.splice(index, 1);
      },
      setFilename(event, row) {
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        row.file = file
      },
      save() {
        // axios.post
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Controller.php**

```
 public function store(Request $request) 
{
  // store function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 save() {
 let data = this.rows
          axios
            .post("Url", {
                data
            })
            .then((res) => {
               console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            });
      }
```

ref link https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am now receiving a post 500 internal error which I believe is an error in the controller. After searching, I tried this code and it seems that it is incorrect.   public function store(Request $request) {
 
  $products = json_decode($request->data, true);

    foreach( $products as $product )
    {
        EmployeeObjective::create([
            'kpi_info' => $product['title'],
            'kpa_info' => $product['description'],
        ]);
    }
    
  }

Comment: i have give you axios solution not your controller solution you can dd() what request you are getting then u can write code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
save() {
       axios
            .post("/your/uri", {
                user_id: 1,
                user_name:'jhone doe',
                email:'test@test.com' 
            })
            .then(response => {
               console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
      }
```

You can retrieve your data from your **controller** `$request->user_id`,...,`$request->email`

> **Tip:** if you post any `object`,you must **`JSON.stringify(your_json)`** them and in a response data from controller **`json_decode($your_json,true)`** or you need to modify your header file.
>
> Always use '**`/your/uri`**' instead of **`/your/uri/`** without trailing **`'/'`**

Comment: please give up-vote and if you think this is your answer,please mark it as a answer- it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It now works. I'll be posting my code just in case someone encounter the same hurdle. Than you very much to **@kamlesh-paul** and **@md-amirozzaman**

**Component.vue**

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: ()=> ({
      rows: [],
    }),

    methods: {
      addRow() {
        this.rows.push({
          corporate_objective_id: '',
          kpa: '',
          kpi: '',
          weight: '',
          score: '',
          equal: '',
          file: {
            name: 'Choose File'
          }
        });
      },
      removeElement(index) {
          this.rows.splice(index, 1);
      },
      setFilename(event, row) {
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        row.file = file
      },
      save() {
        const postData = {
          data: this.rows
        }
        console.log(postData)
        axios
        .post('/api/employee-objective', {postData})
        .then(res => { console.log(res) })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Controller.php**

```
  public function store(Request $request) {
    foreach($request->data as $data) {
      $container = EmployeeObjective::updateOrCreate([
        'kpa_info' => $data['kpa'],
        'kpi_info' => $data['kpi'],
        'kpa_weight' => $data['weight'],
        'kpa_score_1' => $data['score'],
        'kpa_equal' => $data['equal'],
       ]);
      $container->save();
    }
  }
```